# USB-C display compatibility

Tags: microsoft-surface, usb-c, thunderbolt

I'm searching for a monitor to connect it to my Surface Book 3 15". And I want to use only the USB-C cabele (also use to load my laptop). The Surface Book offers USB 3.x Gen 2 @ 10Gb/s DP alt mode with DisplayPort 1.4 bandwidth (HBR3 + DSC)

Does it work with a monitor that supports DP 1.2 and 1.4 but without HBR3 support?

Or will it work with a monitor that has a thunderbolt connector. Can I connect the 3.x Gen 2 to Thunderbolt - is Thunderbolt "downward compatible"?

Comment: you already asked it here https://superuser.com/questions/1611594/monitor-for-surface-book-3 which got closed. It's off-topic for Super User.

Comment: @spikey_richie I would take this question to be more "given these specifications will two things work" than "what monitor should I buy". Granted somewhat similar but going by the wording of our close reason this is subtly different and possibly more on the side of being on-topic rather than shoot-on-sight.